# Stripe Setup with Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I've seen in another tutorial that the steps to access Stripe in Laravel are:

1. composer require stripe/stripe-php
2. php artisan make:controller StripeController
3. make a function within the StripeController class to handle checkout that first accesses your stripe private key

So, here is my code following these steps:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;


class StripeController extends Controller
{
    
public function checkout() {
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env("STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY");
}
}
```

However, when I do this, I get an error on \Stripe\Stripe that says "Undefined type 'Stripe\Stripe'". How do I fix this? It seems like it expects there to be a "Stripe" folder somewhere.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have `use Stripe;` in your code?

Comment: I haven't used it yet because the line \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env("STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY"); throws an error, "Undefined type 'Stripe\Stripe'". I don't understand why it has this error.

Comment: You need to have  the line`use Stripe;` first before using \Stripe\Stripe at all

Comment: Ok Thanks a bunch Karbi! adding the "use Stripe" line fixed the problem.

Comment: Don't access .env directly in your code.  create a config file, or extend an existing config array (such as services.php) and load the key from env in there.